# makefile to start Flask in debug mode

Tags: python, flask, makefile

I would like to start `Flask` in [debug/development mode](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#debug-mode) using a single command.

**Given**

A *fresh* terminal, changing into the project directory, activating a virtual environment and running a custom `Makefile`:

```
> cd project
> activate myenv

(myenv) > make
```

Output

[image]

Debug mode is OFF.  However, running the commands separately turns it ON (as expected):

```
(myenv) > set FLASK_APP=app.py
(myenv) > set FLASK_ENV=development
(myenv) > flask run
```

Output

[image]

**Code**

I've created the following `Makefile`, but when run, the debug mode does not turn on:

`Makefile`

```
all:
    make env && \
    make debug && \
    flask run

env:
    set FLASK_APP=app.py

debug:
    set FLASK_ENV=development
```

How do I improve the `Makefile` to run Flask in debug mode?

Note: [instructions vary slightly for each operating system](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/cli/#cli); at the moment, I am testing this in a Windows command prompt.

Comment: Have you tried setting `all` to : `make env; make debug; flask run` ?

Comment: On windows the only way to get this to work as-is would be changing the recipes to `setx FLASK_APP app.py` etc. If this is the entirety of your makefile however you are using the wrong tool for the job, this should just be a batch file. As the first line in the [make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overview.html#Overview) says: "The make utility automatically determines which pieces of a large program need to be recompiled, and issues commands to recompile them."

Comment: @JacobIRR I have tried this in the past.  I get a `No rule to make target 'env;. 
 Stop.'`

Comment: @user657267 Thanks. `setx` did not work.  I eventually want to extend the file to work in bash terminals.  I'll try a batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makefiles should be deterministic. Having one command which could toggle between the two is not the best way to do it.

Simply create your makefile like so:

```
FLASK_APP = app.py
FLASK := FLASK_APP=$(FLASK_APP) env/bin/flask

.PHONY: run
run:
    FLASK_ENV=development $(FLASK) run

.PHONY: run-production
run-production:
    FLASK_ENV=production $(FLASK) run
```

Now you can just do

```
make run
```

or

```
make run-production
```

Comment: What do your `development` and `production` commands invoke?

Comment: Those aren't commands, they're variable values. `FLASK_ENV` is a variable that flask reads. `make run` invokes `FLASK_ENV=development FLASK_APP=app.py env/bin/flask run`. 
`make run-production` invokes `FLASK_ENV=production FLASK_APP=app.py env/bin/flask run`

Answer (score 1):

While I still believe a `Makefile` is a more general approach on other systems, I settled with @user657267's recommendation to use a batch file on Windows:

**Code**

```
# start_flask.bat
:: set environment varibles (app and debug mode)
set FLASK_APP=app.py
set FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
pause
```

**Demo**

```
> start_flask.bat
```

Output

```
set FLASK_APP=app.py

set FLASK_ENV=development

flask run
 * Serving Flask app "app.py" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * ...
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I am willing accept another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, on Linux inside of a makefile you can place everything on a single line without `export` keyword.

```
debug:
    FLASK_APP=app.py FLASK_ENV=development flask run
```

As per [flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#environments).